# Converting Geometry to long/lat

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, postgis

So in PostgreSQL I have a bunch geometry values for long/lat that are formatted like:

```
0101000020E610000095B9F94674CF37C09CBF0985083B5040
```

So in Postgres I can make a select query that formats everything Ex.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(position_geom)FROM reports;
```

So I have postgreSQL and PostGIS JDBC drivers installed in `eclipse` and thought I could do something similar to

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ST_AsText(*)FROM reports");
while(rs.next()){
String geomVal = rs.getString("position_geom"); 
System.out.println(geomVal);}
```

But I'm getting an ERROR:

```
function st_astext() does not exist.
```

I've imported all the `postGIS` extensions, just wondering if anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format is the Extended Well-Known Binary (EWKB), which is what PostGIS uses for storing `geometry` data in PostgreSQL. The `ST_AsText()` function turns this into the Well-Known Text (WKT) format.

The `ST_AsText()` function needs a single column with a `geometry` data type. So change your code as follows:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ST_AsText(position_geom) AS position_txt FROM reports");
while(rs.next()){ 
String geomVal = rs.getString("position_txt"); 
System.out.println(geomVal);}
```